# How can I deploy my ready website?

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-applications, web-deployment

I have well developed an ASP.NET website with SQL Server 2000. How can I drop it on a server?

Answer (score 1):

You might find these resources helpful:

[ASP.NET Web Site Project Deployment Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/377y0s6t.aspx)

[Deploying a Database by Using the Database Publishing Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907585.aspx)

[How to: Deploy a Database With a Web Application Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465343.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on a number of things (e.g. if you have direct access to the server(s)). I tend to export my database structure as a SQL script and execute that against the production database. I then "publish" the site using VS and copy it across to a virtual directory on the web server.

If I am passing the application to a customer, I tend to use WiX or a VS deployment project to wrap the application up in an installer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Server Publisher (free) wizard for moving database from development machine to the server. Or you can use SQL Server database schema synchronization tool by Red-gate.com

And SitePubisher for deploying files over FTP (and VPN)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.

Read this - http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Deploy-ASP.NET.aspx